# creating inset Space for UILabel

Tags: swift, uilabel

anyone knows how can i get the Inset gap from every direction in a UIlabel

i did this but its giving me the gap from only right side and from up side (from X and Y coordinates )

```
 class LabelClass: UILabel {

override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let newRect = CGRectOffset(rect, 10, 0) // move text 10 points to the right
    super.drawTextInRect(newRect)
}
```

}

if anybody knows how to get that inset space then please let me know and if 
 my question is not understandable than please let me know i'll fix this , thanks :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i think you should use an View at the background of your UIlabel and and make its background same as you'r uilabel's  bg is

```
 theLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "blah")!)
```

something like this

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert a spacing on each side of a `UILabel`, you can simply re-set it's frame, inserting the space by altering each component

```
let frame: CGRect = myLabel.frame
let myOffset: CGFloat = 4 //set this to whatever you want

myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(
    frame.minX - myOffset, //subtract offset from the original X (minX)
    frame.minY - myOffset, //subtract offset from the original Y (minY)
    frame.width + (myOffset * 2), //add offset * 2 to the original width
    frame.height + (myOffset * 2) //add offset * 2 to the original height
)
```

For example, if the offset was one

```
 Subtracted one from the original x position (frame.minX)
 |
 |        Added (1 * 2) = two to the original width (frame.width)
 |        ||
 v        vv

 >+++++++++<   <- Subtracted one from the original y position (frame.minY)
 >         <
 >  Label  <
 >         <   <-
 >+++++++++<   <- Added (1 * 2) = two to the original height (frame.height)

  >+++++++<
  > Label <
  >+++++++<
```

The text stays in the same place, but the frame is changed to add the spacing desired

On the other hand, if you want to add *padding* from the superview, you just need to reverse the signs in the above code

```
let frame: CGRect = myLabel.frame
let myOffset: CGFloat = 4 //set this to whatever you want

myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(
    frame.minX + myOffset, //subtract offset from the original X (minX)
    frame.minY + myOffset, //subtract offset from the original Y (minY)
    frame.width - (myOffset * 2), //add offset * 2 to the original width
    frame.height - (myOffset * 2) //add offset * 2 to the original height
)
```

Comment: hey thanks for answering @jojodmo but  `frame.x` this lines is giving error `CGRect has no member x` you mean `maXx` ?

Comment: hey @jojodmo i just updated my question with what i tried  am i missing something ? because its not doing anything ?

Comment: i loaded it at UITableViewCell class

Comment: @Montanabucks Instead of updating the original post with another question, you should instead either post a new question, or, as this question pertains to one of the answers, you should just discuss the problem in the comments - anyways, does the code just not do anything?

Comment: in comments codes are so hard to understand thats why i updated the question , yeah its not doing anything am i doing it properly ?

Comment: Try setting the background color to `UIColor.redColor()` or something that is easy to see. Also, try adding the label to the superview again, and make sure you *aren't* calling `sizeToFit()` or anything on the label after updating the frame

Comment: i am using this tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 68.0
        
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
  is it the reason why its not working ?

Comment: I haven't done much with rows in `UITableViews`, so try removing that. Also, did you try what I mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: still not getting desired output :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99575/discussion-between-jojodmo-and-montana-bucks).